# How do I test my sub-query returning null records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have query which needs to update some tuples of another table, I only need to update two records, the values corresponding to each record is fetch from another table, currently my query working fine, no typos, no error, but it fetches zero records and hence my other tables',I figured it out that my inner sub-query didn't get able to fetch the relevant data, but I am not able to test my inner sub query as it requires the reference of two tables

here is the query

```
UPDATE SALARY_DETAIL_TBL sd
SET GROSS_EARNING =(SELECT AMOUNT FROM SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT sr WHERE sd.EMP_ID = sr.EMP_ID AND sr.PAY_CODE = 997) ,
  GROSS_DEDUCTION =
  (SELECT AMOUNT
  FROM SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT sr
  WHERE sd.EMP_ID = sr.EMP_ID
  AND sr.PAY_CODE = 998
  )
WHERE (GROSS_EARNING IS NULL
OR GROSS_DEDUCTION   IS NULL)
```

Columns `GROSS_EARNING` and `GROSS_DEDUCTION` populated by inner query and that inner query produces zero result and I want to test is separately, kindly suggest me the best possible solutions.

Now it throws

```
UPDATE SALARY_DETAIL_TBL sd
    SET GROSS_EARNING =(SELECT AMOUNT FROM SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT sr WHERE sd.EMP_ID = sr.EMP_ID AND sr.PAY_CODE = 997) ,
      GROSS_DEDUCTION =
      (SELECT AMOUNT
      FROM SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT sr
      WHERE sd.EMP_ID = sr.EMP_ID
      AND sr.PAY_CODE = 998
      )
    WHERE (GROSS_EARNING IS NULL
    OR GROSS_DEDUCTION   IS NULL)

BadSqlGrammerException: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check with the query whether the data exists in the tables at all

```
SELECT AMOUNT 
  FROM SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT sr 
 WHERE sr.EMP_ID in(select EMP_ID  
                      from SALARY_DETAIL_TBL sd 
                      where (GROSS_EARNING IS NULL
                             OR GROSS_DEDUCTION   IS NULL) 
                    )  
  AND sr.PAY_CODE in (997,998)
```

Comment: thanks dear, but whats wrong with my inner query, it should fetch the proper data, I still puzzled about this. Can you figured out?

Comment: @user9634982 there is nothing wrong. Since I do not know exactly what the data in your table look like, I can not say more exactly

Comment: Hey I fixed the query, but now it throws an SqlGrammerException, see my recent edit

Comment: @user9634982 as the exception says, your subquery returns more than one value. In the `SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT` table, there are more than one record for an `EMP_ID` and with id `997` or `998`. there you have to restrict the query, to the right value

Answer (score 1):

You have two assignments:

```
GROSS_EARNING =
 (SELECT AMOUNT FROM SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT sr
  WHERE sd.EMP_ID = sr.EMP_ID AND sr.PAY_CODE = 997)
```

and

```
GROSS_DEDUCTION =
 (SELECT AMOUNT FROM SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT sr
  WHERE sd.EMP_ID = sr.EMP_ID AND sr.PAY_CODE = 998)
```

and you expect both to return one row at most.

So check whether there are `EMP_ID` with multiple matches per `PAY_CODE`:

```
select emp_id, pay_code, count(*)
from salary_detail_report
where pay_code in (997, 998)
group by emp_id, pay_code
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

And you can check whether there is unreferenced data with

```
SELECT AMOUNT 
  FROM SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT sr 
 WHERE sr.EMP_ID not in(select EMP_ID  
                      from SALARY_DETAIL_TBL sd 
                      where (GROSS_EARNING IS NULL
                             OR GROSS_DEDUCTION   IS NULL) 
                    )  
  AND sr.PAY_CODE in (997,998)
```

Comment: thanks dear, but whats wrong with my inner query, it should fetch the proper data, I still puzzled about this. Can you figured out?

Comment: Please do not post more than one answer to a thread. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. If you need to revise or clarify a response please **edit your first answer** instead of adding a second one.

Comment: Sorry I'll do, I'm new to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems you have multiple rows with the same emp_id and the same pay_code.
You should first check if that's correct, if so define a strategy to select which one is the right one to update the other table, otherwise just remove the wrong rows.
For example, if you have some date in the row you could order by that date and limit the results to 1.

```
(SELECT AMOUNT
      FROM SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT sr
      WHERE sd.EMP_ID = sr.EMP_ID
      AND sr.PAY_CODE = 998
ORDER BY sr.some_column_that_makes_sense
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)
```

Comment: `LIMIT` does not exists in oracle

Comment: right, sorry! I edited the code, try OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY or FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS

Comment: To be clear this syntax is [new to Orcale 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABEAACC). Everybody should be on 12c, because all older versions are deprecated and basically out of support. But a lot of organisations are still using 11g or older anyway.